# Background playback of videos in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I have the following code:

```
MediaPlayer media = new MediaPlayer(MediaManager.createMedia(thePath, true));
media.setAutoplay(true);
video.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, media);
```

that works. I want that the users can continue to "listen to" the video if they want to put the smartphone in their pocket. It can make sense when the video doesn't requires to be watched (like for a talking, a conference or other similar talking videos). Usually an user presses the hardware button to power off the screen before putting him/her smartphone in the pocket, that means to put the app in the background *(I'm not sure if it's exactly as putting the app in the background, please correct me if I'm wrong).*

Moreover, I want that the users can continue to "watch to" the video if they put the app from background to foreground.

How can I implement this use case with Codename One?

In this blog post https://www.codenameone.com/blog/material-icons-background-music-geofencing-gradle.html, there is a section about "Background Music", but this use case is different. I need "Background video".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iOS the build hint `ios.background_modes=music` build hint should work. Android might be more problematic as it requires a different media API call and right now that media API call is designed for audio.

It's possible that you can detect suspend (`stop` call) and stop the video playback then switch to `MediaManager.createBackgroundMedia()` and continue from the same offset. Then detect the `start()` call to resume the video. I haven't tried this though and I'm not sure if it's the right way to do this.